# Prepend a form field response in Angular 2

Tags: forms, angular, prepend

I'm building a registration form in Angular 2 that asks a user to provide their website's URL before submitting.

When the form is submitted, I need the provided URL to be in the style of "http://www.google.com". To steer the user towards that format, I want the form field to autofill the initial "http://" as soon as the user clicks on the field (or when the user begins typing - either case would be acceptable). Currently I have placeholder text in the field that says "Please provide your website's URL", but I'm having trouble making the "http://" prefix appear when the user actually clicks on the field or starts typing.

Any ideas would be appreciated. [Here is what the form field looks like when the user clicks on it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzOOW.png) It's contents should switch to "http://" when clicked or typed in. Here is what the code looks like at the moment:

```
<div class="form-group">

  <input
    class="form-control"
    type="text"
    name="companyUrl"
    [(ngModel)]="user.companyUrl"
    placeholder="Company url"
    required pattern='https?://.+'
    #companyUrl
   >

    <div *ngIf="companyUrl.errors && (companyUrl.dirty || companyUrl.touched)" class="text-danger">
      <div [hidden]="!companyUrl.errors.required">
        Company URL is required.
      </div>
      <div [hidden]="!companyUrl.errors.pattern">
        URL should begin with http:// or https://
      </div>
    </div>

<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a function to add the prefix on click event of the input.
Something like below:

```
<input #companyUrl  (click)="addHttpPrefix()" >
```

And in this function
1. Get the value of companyUrl.
2. Check if it begins with http then skip else prepend with http://

```
if(companyUrl.indexOf('http') > -1) {
    companyUrl = 'http://' + companyUrl;
}
```

This way when the user initially clicks on the input http:// would be appended.
if the (click) event does not meet your requirement you can try using (change) or other events.